# Flutter "CircularProgressIndicator" widgets breaks widgets alignement

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently building a scrapping a scrapping application using flutter.

I encounter a problem when I try to display a loader while scrapping, the apparition of the loader seems to totally break the Cross Axis Alignement of my Columns.

First my application looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tbz7.png

Then, when I hit "scrap button", I update my state in order to display a loader, and this happens :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MIi6.png

Here are the two pieces of code rendering the application :

*My main class rendering a Flutter logo & my main widget*

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FlutterLogo(
              size: 400,
              style: FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal,
            ),
            ScrapBody(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*My main Widget containing rendering management logic as follow*

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ScrapForm(
          scrap: scrap,
          exportToCsv: exportToCsv,
          isScrapSuccess: isScrapSuccess,
        ),
        isLoading
            // ? Container()
            ? Column(
                children: [
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  Text(
                    "Scrapping page ${pageScrapIndex.toString()} on ${totalPages.toString()}",
                  ),
                ],
              )
            : Column(
                children: [
                  ScrapResult(
                    reviewerListResult: reviewerList,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

As you can see, I tried to constraint the widgets that composes my Column with " crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center" in both parts, but it doesn't work, the widgets keeps goes on the left when I render my loader, and only when I render my loader.

After many searches about the Circuler loader and a look in the widget core,I didn't find anything that could explain my case, any help would be so
appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to wrap your base column with `Container` and give it's width as `double.infinity`. and also add  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` for your circular progress dialog's `Column` if the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot aligur, for more precision : adding width:double.infinty to my Container was the thing, but the crossAlignement thing for my circular loader didn't had any effet.